# IOException doesn't give enough information

Tags: java, android

My android program isn't working. I am using normal client-server sockets. I have tested my server with telnet and it works fine, but when I try it with my android program, it doesn't work (more details in a second). Here's my code:

```
 Socket s = null;
 try
 {
    String SocketServerAddress = db.getPhSsServerAddress();
    Integer SocketServerPort = db.getPhSsServerPort();
    s = new Socket(SocketServerAddress, SocketServerPort);
    Log.d(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "Setting up Socket: " + SocketServerAddress + ":" + SocketServerPort);
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    Log.d(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "Connected to: " + s.getInetAddress() + " on port " + s.getPort());

    out.writeUTF("Helo, Server");
    out.flush();
    Log.d(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "Bytes written: " + out.size());
    String st = in.readUTF();

    Log.d(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "SocketServerResponse: " + st);
 }
 catch (UnknownHostException e) 
 {
    Log.e(MY_ERROR_TAG, "UnknownHostException: " + e.getMessage() + "; " + e.getCause());
   } 
 catch (IOException e) 
   {
    Log.e(MY_ERROR_TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage() + "; " + e.getCause() + "; " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
   }
 finally
 {
    try {
            s.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(MY_ERROR_TAG, "IOException on socket.close(): " + e.getMessage() + "; " + e.getCause());
        }
 }
```

All I ever get here is a thrown IOException with no message or cause attached. The specific line causing the error is the String st = in.readUTF().  If I comment out that line, my code runs fine (no exceptions thrown), but my server does not acknowledge that any data has been sent to it. And of course I don't get any data back since that line is commented out.

So, how can I figure out what the problem is? Tonight I am going to try and see what is being passed with wireshark to see if that gives any insight.

Comment: You should consider adding the exception on the end of all of your `Log.e()` methods.  They can do `e("tag", "msg")` or `e("tag", "msg", throwable)`.  If you log the complete throwable you may get more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the server using `readUTF()` and `writeUTF()` too? `writeUTF()` writes data in a unique format that can only be understood by `readUTF(),` which won't understand anything else.

**EDIT** `EOFException` means that there is no more data. You should catch it separately and handle it by closing the socket etc. It can certainly be caused spuriously by `readUTF()` trying to read data that wasn't written with `writeUTF().`

And deciding it was an `IOException` when it was really an `EOFException` means you didn't print out or log the exception itself, just its message. Always use the log methods provided for exceptions, or at least use `Exception.toString().`

Comment: OMG, that was it. Wow, I have been troubleshooting this all day. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I see your edit and have more questions. Previously, I had "decided" it wan an IOException because that is what I saw in the log: "IOException: null, null, null". The nulls were because the getMessage, getCause and getLocalizedMessage all returned null??? I found this code on the web and didn't think to see if there were any other exceptions I could catch. Can you give me an example of a good log method to print out useful information as you are suggestion?

Comment: @MrGibbage You've already had several suggestions. I don't know how you got the output you got but it can't have been by calling any exception-specific log method I've ever used.

Comment: Just checking, but most of the time those `EOFException`s are not going to have an error message, correct?

Answer (score -1):

As I remember I had a problem with DataInpuStream some day... try doing so:

```
in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: Kerai, sadly, that did not help. @Gray, thanks for the tip. I had never seen that before. I logged Log.e(MY_ERROR_TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage() + "; " + e.getCause() + "; " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e); and in eclipse, I saw the full error following my log statement. It looks like this is a java.io.EOFException. I'm not really sure how I am going to fix that one. :(